# Android Studio Java Syntax Color Scheme

Tags: java, android, android-studio, syntax, color-scheme

I am using the latest Android Studio version at this time (2.3.3) and I did not have much experience with Android Studio before, when I started to use it now, I feel a bit uncomfortable with the Java syntax.

I do understand that there is a way of changing each attribute colour, if you go to "`Editor> Colors & Fonts> Java`" I will be able to modify the Scheme myself, but I'm not too sure about how to manage it.

I've been using Eclispe and SublimeText before, and in Sublime it is much easier to understand the code and visually get around.

**Android Studio Syntax:**
[image: Android Studio Syntax]

**Sublime Text Syntax:**
[image: Sublime Text Syntax]

Maybe there is a way around it, where I can import a scheme or a tutorial how to set the correct colours for a correct attributes?

For those that are trying to achieve what I wanted, there is a GitHub repo called [sdvoynikov/color-themes](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes) where you can download a lot of themes from there and then import into an Android Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1 : Download [`jetbrains-monokai-sublime`](https://github.com/OtaK/jetbrains-monokai-sublime) theme

Step 2 : Extract the zip.

Step 3 : Go to `File -> import settings -> and select the Monokai-Sublime.jar` where you previously extracted the zip.

and you are done

Comment: This one works more or less, however, you will need to modify some of the attributes depending on what colour-scheme you are using (dark or light). But that is what I wanted, thank you.

Comment: yeah with little adjustment , it will be pretty fine and i am glad that i could help , happy colorful coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Install [Java Code Styles](https://github.com/square/java-code-styles), which is compatible with IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio.